# No member function declared in class when using "interface"

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

I want to implement a interface Formatter with some static methods, then create another classes who implements that methods. I do something like that:

**Formatter.hpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Matrix.hpp"

#ifndef FORMATTER_HPP
#define FORMATTER_HPP

class Formatter {
public:
    /**
     * Retorna uma string que pode ser usada no symbolab para testes
     */
    static std::string matrixString(Matrix* matrix);
    /**
     * Retorna string para symbolab para transposição da matriz
     */
    static std::string transposedMatrixString(Matrix* matrix);
    /**
     * Retorna string para symbolab da soma de duas matrizes
     */
    static std::string matrixSumString(Matrix* m1, Matrix* m2);
    /**
     * Retorna string para symbolab do produto de duas matrizes
     */
    static std::string matrixProductString(Matrix* m1, Matrix* m2);
    /**
     * Retorna string para symbolab da determinante de uma matriz
     */
    static std::string matrixDeterminantString(Matrix* matrix);
};

#endif
```

**SymbolabFormatter.hpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Formatter.hpp"

#ifndef SYMBOLABFORMATTER_HPP
#define SYMBOLABFORMATTER_HPP

class SymbolabFormatter: public Formatter{
public:
    SymbolabFormatter();
};

#endif
```

**SymbolabFormatter.cpp**

```
#include "SymbolabFormatter.hpp"
#include <sstream>

std::string SymbolabFormatter::matrixString(Matrix* matrix) {
    ...
}

std::string SymbolabFormatter::transposedMatrixString(Matrix *matrix) {
    ...
}

std::string SymbolabFormatter::matrixSumString(Matrix *m1, Matrix *m2) {
    ...
}

std::string SymbolabFormatter::matrixProductString(Matrix *m1, Matrix *m2) {
    ...
}

std::string SymbolabFormatter::matrixDeterminantString(Matrix* matrix) {
    ...
}
```

But doesn't work. When i compile that, this errors are showed:
[Image from compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBWLV.png)

*PS.: Sorry some grammar error, my english is terrible.*

Comment: Why are your `#include` guards not placed at the top of your header files?

Comment: I am new in C++... and i didn't understand your question... I guess the #include are in the right place... If not, where put then?

Comment: I am speaking of the #ifndef FORMATTER_HPP / #define FORMATTER_HPP and similar lines that(you say you're new to C++, but apparently didn't know those are called include guards). Open any standard header, like <vector> or <string>. Where do you see those include guards placed? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Include_Guard_Macro

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks by the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot define `SymbolabFormatter::matrixString` unless you declare it as a member function of the class.

Declaring the member function in the base class does not equate to declaring it in the derived class.

Comment: But according with that tutorial [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm) it was to work...

Comment: You can call the member functions of the base class through the derived class (with some constraints) but you can't define them like they were declared in the derived class.

Comment: That tutorial doesn't use `static`.

Comment: @AlanStokes, the issue is same whether the function is `static` or not. A function can be defined using the `Symbolab::` scope only if it is declared in the class.